# In Spark AR, how do I enable different custom instructions based on which camera is active?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I am trying to make some patches that essentially say,

if front camera is active, display instructions "flip the camera"

if back camera is active, display instructions "tap to start" after 2 seconds

I've tried to show that in the patches below, but I know I'm using the Available Tokens Option Picker incorrectly. Any suggestions? Not a lot of documentation on this.
[image]

I tried modifying that to select 0 or 1 but I can't seem to do that with the if then else (as I've attempted below):
[image]

Any suggestions? This is definitely a data type issue, but I am not sure which patches would be best to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I found an elegant solution for this, which works only because the camera is either front or back (binary option):
[image: Patch sequence to change instruction based on camera selected]

I don't have an answer for >2 instructions in the option picker just yet, but I think the community would benefit it someone knows that particular solution.